# Balance on plain

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading an algebra book. It said that an balance on see-saw can be viewed as two vector's dot product equal to zero. 
Like: Put weight 4 at the point $x=-1$ and a weight of 2  at the point $x=2$, will being balance on center point because vector of weight: $$ w = (4,2)$$ and vector of position $$ v=(-1,2)$$ We have $$w\cdot v = 0$$
So I am wondering, what if I have a plain and bunch of point with weigh, Like weight 4 at point (-2,0) and weight 2 at point (1,1) and weight 2 at point(1,-1),Are those particle will being balance? Dose we have some sort of matrix or vector form of formula can assert whether these point will balance or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the center of mass in the $x$ and $y$ direction separately. So, if you have points $(x_1,y_1),\dots (x_n,y_n)$ with masses $m_1,m_2\dots m_n$, then the center of mass (where you have to support the plane to balance them) is calculated as

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{m_i\cdot x_i}{M}, \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{m_i\cdot y_i}{M}\right)$$

where $M$ is the total mass of all the weigths combined.

So, these points will balance at $(0,0)$ if and only if both $$\sum_{i=1}^nm_ix_i=0$$
and $$\sum_{i=1}^nm_ix_i=0$$

Comment: Possible matrix representation:
$\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1}       & x_{2} & x_{3} & \dots & x_{n} \\
    y_{1}       & y_{2} & y_{3} & \dots & y_{n} \\
\end{bmatrix}$ $\vec{m} = \vec{0}$

Comment: Ok, I got the picture, What you are saying is to split the coordinate of each point and make sure they balance on that coordinate, right?

Comment: @zeyangyue Precisely.

Answer (score 0):

The best method to find if your points will be balanced in a particular arrangement is to first find a centre of symmetry. Believe me finding the centre/axis of symmetry will reduce a lot of your work. First find the centre of symmetry for the two 2 kgs weight. From there build up to finding the centre of mass of the combined system and that of the 4 kg weight.

The reason I emphasized on finding the axis/centre of symmetry is that it will lead a long way for you to identify just by doing some trivial calculations for some easy coordinates before you can decide if the system will balance or not.  If you can't seem to find a stable centre/axis of symmetry then the system will not balance no matter what thus saving you a lot of work. Cheers